# Need Perl script for authorize and authenticate users on RADIUS server?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl script. My task is to login on RADIUS Server and Verifying the user is authorized one.

But i don't know how to do it using perl script on a ubuntu system.

Also i need to know, how i get login Id and password for Radius server.

please guide me with an Example if possible.

Thank U all,

Answer (score 2):

Try [Auth::Simple::RADIUS](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Authen-Simple-RADIUS-0.1/). It is the easiest know.

Comment: Thanks But I need to know how to get the required username and password