# how to login/register on RADIUS server using perl?

Tags: perl

I'm Novice for Perl. How to register/login in RADIUS server using perl?

give me an example script to analysis.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Perl script for authorize and authenticate users on RADIUS server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978580/need-perl-script-for-authorize-and-authenticate-users-on-radius-server)

Answer (score 1):

[This module is the first search result](http://search.cpan.org/~manowar/RadiusPerl-0.12/Radius.pm) from Google, which includes example code.